# What do these error messages mean when numerically solving differential equations?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am using *Mathematica* to numercially solve the following equations:

```
2 D[f0[r], r]/r + D[f0[r], r, r] == -2 A f1[r]/r^4 +  2 A D[f1[r], 
r]/r^3 -2 f1[r]/r^2 + 2 D[f1[r], r]/r + D[f1[r], r, r] == 2 A D[f0[r], r]/r^3
```

And my boundary condition is

```
f0[10] == 0.01, f1[10] == 0.01, 
(D[f0[r], r] /. r -> 1) == 10^-3 A, 
(D[f1[r], r] /. r -> 1) == 0
```

When I take A to be small, say 1, everything is fine. However, if I take A
to be large, e.g. 100, *Mathematica* complains and gives me crazy results. 
Here are the error message I get:

> NDSolve::bvluc: The equations derived from the boundary conditions are
>   numerically ill-conditioned. The boundary conditions may not be sufficient
>   to uniquely define a solution. The computed solution may match the boundary
>   conditions poorly. >>
>
> NDSolve::berr: There are significant errors {-5.55116*10^6,-7.26312*10^6,0.,
>   0.} in the boundary value residuals. Returning the best solution found. >>

Can anyone help me to deal with this issue?  I appreciate your help!

Comment: Could you tell us more precisely what you mean by "deal with this issue"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  The equations I am trying to solve are well defined, Mathematica has already provided the correct answer when A is small.  However, it seems that Mathematica has some technical issue when I increase A.  For example when A is 100, the result blows up at r=10, which is not consistent with the boundary conditions.  My question is whether there is a way (option), for example the steps of iterations, which I can play with to make Mathematica solve the equations properly when A is large.

Comment: Exactly how are you using *Mathematica* to solve these equations?  `NDSolve` does a fine job if you solve for `f0` first and then for `f1` in terms of it.

Comment: I combine equations and boundary conditions into a larger set of equations, and use NDSolve for the problem.
NDSolve[{equations, boundary conditions}, {f0[r], f1[r]}, {r, 1, 10}]
What do you mean by solving f0 first and then for f1 in terms of it?  They are coupled to each other, how do you separate them off?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: `f0` is evidently independent: `2 D[f0[r], r]/r + D[f0[r], r, r] == 2 A D[f0[r], r]/r^3`

Answer (score 1):

You may solve this by increasing the `WorkingPrecision` like so:

```
eqn = {2 D[f0[r], r]/r + D[f0[r], r, r] == -2 A f1[r]/r^4 + 
     2 A D[f1[r], r]/r^3,
   -2 f1[r]/r^2 + 2 D[f1[r], r]/r + D[f1[r], r, r] == 
    2 A D[f0[r], r]/r^3};
bc = {f0[10] == 1/100, 
   f1[10] == 1/100, (D[f0[r], r] /. r -> 1) == 
    10^-3 A, (D[f1[r], r] /. r -> 1) == 0};

A = 80
NDSolve[{eqn, bc}, {f0, f1}, {r, 1, 10}, WorkingPrecision -> 60, 
 MaxSteps -> Infinity]
A =.;
```