# NDSolve issuing boundary condition error message

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, finite-element-method

I would like to solve this non-linear differential equation with boundary conditions and a small perturbation (eps):

```
eps = 0.01;
eq = (eps^2) y''[x] + eps*x*y'[x] - y[x] == -Exp[x];
bcs = {y[0] == 2, y[1] == 1};
s = NDSolve[{eq, bcs}, y, {x, 0, 1}]
Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. s], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

But the solution does not fit the BC: (expected due to this error)

> NDSolve: The equations derived from the boundary conditions are
>   numerically ill-conditioned. The boundary conditions may not be
>   sufficient to uniquely define a solution. If a solution is computed,
>   it may match the boundary conditions poorly.

So I tried different methods such as : "Chasing" or "Shooting". ([Infos](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveBVP.html)), but none of them match the both bondary conditions simultaneously.

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems like you're perturbing the equation `y[x] == Exp[x]`, which itself does not satisfy the BCs. It's not surprising it's ill-conditioned. It's probably unstable as `eps` goes to zero. I suppose this is what you're studying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Introduction

I would have done a Chebyshev approach earlier, but a stupid, elusive typo kept the accuracy low.  The method is fast and highly accurate, although for the code below, recursive refinement and a convergence test have not been implemented (the idea would be the same as used for `` cheb`approx `` in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128802/4999)).

A discussion of this approach, as well as an example over an infinite interval, may be found in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/114658/4999).  Here we need only a simple affine transformation of a finite interval to the standard Chebyshev interval $[-1, 1]$. See [Boyd, Chebyshev and Fourier Spectral Methods (2001)](https://books.google.com/books?id=b4TCAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Boyd+Chebyshev+and+Fourier+Spectral+Methods&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjlzv7iqcvMAhXDSyYKHYj6Dk0Q6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=Boyd%20Chebyshev%20and%20Fourier%20Spectral%20Methods&f=false) for more.

### OP's problem

For convenience, here is the OP's setup:

```
eps = 1/100;
eq = (eps^2) y''[x] + eps*x*y'[x] - y[x] == -Exp[x];
bcs = {y[0] == 2, y[1] == 1};
```

#### Chebyshev series solutions of linear, second-order BVPs

First we give a general function that will solve a linear, second-order BVP.  It depends on some utilities given at the end.

```
ClearAll[chebLinearSecondOrderBVP, chebLinearSecondOrderBVP`parse];
Options[chebLinearSecondOrderBVP] = {WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision};
SetAttributes[chebLinearSecondOrderBVP`parse, HoldAllComplete];
(* parses the input; TBD: error messages! *)
chebLinearSecondOrderBVP`parse[
   chebLinearSecondOrderBVP[sys_, y_, {x_, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ}, 
    n_, opts : OptionsPattern[chebLinearSecondOrderBVP]]] := 
  Module[{ode, bcs, odebcs, dorder, y1, y2, prec},
   With[{f = FreeQ[#, y[x] | Derivative[_][y][x]] &},
    odebcs = SortBy[f]@GatherBy[sys, f]
    ];
   If[Length /@ odebcs == {1, 2},
    {{ode}, bcs} = odebcs, 
    Return[$Failed]];
   {y1, y2} = {y[a], y[b]} /. First@Solve[bcs, {y[a], y[b]}];
   If[! VectorQ[{y1, y2}, NumericQ], Return[$Failed]];
   dorder = Max@Cases[ode, Derivative[k_][y][x] :> k, Infinity];
   If[dorder != 2, Return[$Failed]];
   If[! Internal`LinearQ[ode, {y[x], y'[x], y''[x]}], Return[$Failed]];
   prec = OptionValue[chebLinearSecondOrderBVP, opts, WorkingPrecision];
   {ode, y1, y2, prec}
   ];
call : chebLinearSecondOrderBVP[ 
    sys_, y_, {x_, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ}, n_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{ode, y1, y2, xvec, dm, dops, opL, load, dy, yvec, cc, prec, res},
   res = chebLinearSecondOrderBVP`parse[call]; (* parse arguments *)
   (
     {ode, y1, y2, prec} = res;
     (* construct differential operator  opL  for the ode *)
     ode = Normal@ CoefficientArrays[ode /. Equal -> Subtract, {y[x], y'[x], y''[x]}];
     {dm, {{xvec}}} = Reap[chebDM[n, prec], "x"];  (* Ch. deriv. operator and pts. *)
     dops = NestList[2/(b - a) dm.# &, IdentityMatrix[n + 1], 2]; (* 0-2 order diff.ops.*) 
     dops = dops[[All, 2 ;; -2, 2 ;; -2]];         (* strip boundary *)
     xvec = Rescale[xvec[[2 ;; -2]], {-1, 1}, {a, b}];
     opL = (ode[[2]] /. x -> xvec) dops // Total;  (* assumes coefficients are Listable *)
     (* construct load and subtract line to make homogeneous BCs y[a]==y[b]==0:
      * the line affects the y[x], y'[x] terms (ode[[2,1;;2]]);
      * it does not affect the y''[x] term
      *)
     load = ode[[1]] /. x -> xvec;
     dy = {(a y2 - b y1 + x (y1 - y2))/(a - b), (y2 - y1)/(b - a)} ode[[2, 1 ;; 2]] /.
        x -> xvec // Total;                        (* impose homogeneous BCs *)
     (* solve BVP, get Chebyshev coeffs and add line back for BVs *)
     yvec = LinearSolve[opL, -load - dy];
     yvec = ArrayPad[yvec, 1, N[0, prec]];         (* added homogenized BCs *)
     cc = chebSeries[yvec];
     cc[[1]] += (y1 + y2)/2;  (* Adjust to BCs *)
     cc[[2]] += (y2 - y1)/2;
     res = chebFunc[cc, {a, b}]
     ) /; FreeQ[res, $Failed | chebLinearSecondOrderBVP`parse]
   ];
```

The solution of the OP's problem:

```
ySol2 = chebLinearSecondOrderBVP[{eq, y[0] == 2, y[1] == 1}, 
   y, {x, 0, 1}, 64, WorkingPrecision -> 32];

Plot[{Exp[x], ySol2[x]}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The solution satisfies the BVP to machine precision

```
Plot[Evaluate[eq /. Equal -> Subtract /. y -> ySol2], {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
{y[0.] - 2, y[1.] - 1} /. y -> ySol2  (* BCs *)
(*  {0., 0.}  *)
```

#### Chebyshev utilities

```
(*
 * Chebyshev series utilities
 *)

ClearAll[chebFunc];
chebFunc::usage = "f = chebFunc[c,{a,b}], c = {c0, c1,..., cn} Chebyshev coefficients, over the interval {a,b}; y = chebFunc[c,{a,b}][x] evaluates the function";
chebFunc[c_, {a_, b_}][x_] := chebFunc[c, {a, b}, x];
chebFunc[c_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &), {a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ}, x_?NumericQ] := 
  ChebyshevT[Range[0, Length[c] - 1], (2 x - (a + b))/(b - a)].c;
chebFunc[c_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &), {a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ}, x_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := 
  Cos[Outer[Times, ArcCos[(2 x - (a + b))/(b - a)], Range[0, Length[c] - 1]]].c;
chebFunc /: Normal[chebFunc[c_?VectorQ, {a_, b_}, x_]] := 
  Evaluate@ChebyshevT[#, (2 x - (a + b))/(b - a)] &[Range[0, Length[c] - 1]].c;
Derivative[_, _, n_][chebFunc][c_, {a_, b_}, x_] /; 0 <= n <= Length@c := 
  chebFunc[Nest[chebDerivative, c, n] (2/(b - a))^n, {a, b}, x];

ClearAll[chebDerivative, chebSeries, chebDM];
chebDerivative::usage = "chebDerivative[c, {a,b}] differentiates the Chebyshev series c scaled over the interval {a,b}";
chebDerivative[c_] := chebDerivative[c, {-1, 1}];
chebDerivative[c_, {a_, b_}] := 
  Module[{c1 = 0, c2 = 0, c3}, 
   2/(b - a) MapAt[#/2 &,
     Reverse@Table[
       c3 = c2;
       c2 = c1;
       c1 = 2 (n + 1)*c[[n + 2]] + c3,
       {n, Length[c] - 2, 0, -1}],
     1]];
chebDM::usage = "chebD[n] = (n+1)x(n+1) Chebyshev spectral differentiation matrix of order n";
chebDM[n_Integer?Positive, prec_ : MachinePrecision] := 
 Module[{fac, xm}, 
  xm = If[prec === MachinePrecision, 
    ConstantArray[Sin[(π Range[N[n], -N[n], -2.])/(2 n)], n + 1], 
    ConstantArray[N[Sin[(π Range[n, -n, -2])/(2 n)], prec], n + 1]];
  Sow[First[xm], "x"]; 
  fac = Flatten[{2, PadRight[{}, n - 1, {-1, 1}], 2 - 4 Mod[n, 2]}]; 
  xm = Outer[Times, fac, 1/fac]/(Transpose[xm] - xm + IdentityMatrix[n + 1]); 
  xm - DiagonalMatrix[Total[xm, {2}]]];

chebSeries::usage = "chebSeries[y] returns the Chebyshev series for the function values y over the standard interval {-1, 1}";
chebSeries[y_] := Module[{cc},
   cc = Sqrt[2/(Length[y] - 1)] FourierDCT[y, 1];
   cc[[{1, -1}]] /= 2; 
   cc];
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are a couple more ways.  The first is similar to @anderstood's, but with a different integration method.  The second uses FEM and has the virtue of being fast.  It appears to be a perturbation of the equation `y[x] == Exp[x]` with discontinuous boundary conditions `y[0] == 2`, `y[1] == 1`.  The problem suffers some from boundary effects.  The options for the first method are set so that this virtually eliminated, except slightly near `x == 1`.  The `PrecisionGoal` has to be set fairly high or the ill-conditioning to great an error. But once it's over the threshold, you get a highly accurate solution.  The FEM is limited to machine precision, and it effectively achieves `PrecisionGoal -> 8` when far enough away from the boundary. If high precision is not needed, it's probably the best method.  Note you have to set the `"MaxCellMeasure"` for it depending on `eps`, perhaps `eps/10` is good enough.

```
Clear[x, y];
eps = 1/100;
eq = (eps^2) y''[x] + eps*x*y'[x] - y[x] == -Exp[x];
bcs = {y[0] == 2, y[1] == 1};

s = NDSolve[{eq, bcs}, y, {x, 0, 1}, Method -> "Extrapolation", 
   PrecisionGoal -> 32, WorkingPrecision -> 60, 
   InterpolationOrder -> All];

s2 = NDSolve[{eq, bcs}, y, {x, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 1/1000}}];
```

Both produces indistinguishable graphs. I compare one with the graph of `Exp[x]`:

```
Plot[Evaluate[{Exp[x], y[x] /. s}], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Evaluating the residual of the ODE shows the boundary effects:

```
Plot[Evaluate[
  eq /. Equal -> Subtract /. Join[s, s2] // RealExponent],
 {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {-36, 0}, PlotPoints -> 200, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 32]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

Increase the working precision (see [22081](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22081/what-do-these-error-messages-mean-when-numerically-solving-differential-equation)) plus `"StiffnessSwitching"` method:

```
eps = 1/100;
eq = (eps^2) y''[x] + eps*x*y'[x] - y[x] == -Exp[x];
bcs = {y[0] == 2, y[1] == 1};
s = NDSolve[{eq, bcs}, y, {x, 0, 1}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
  WorkingPrecision -> 80]
Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. s], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]